How did the Local Interstellar Cloud form?
The Local Interstellar Cloud (LIC) is a low-density interstellar cloud which embed the Sun and other stars.
How did this region form? I suppose a supernova or stellar winds from multiple stars may have been responsible, but I haven't found any confirm from searching on the internet.

Good question. Yet: where did you search and what keywords did you use?

Nice question!. Hmm, I suppose we don't really know, we can't know what happened in the past, I suppose we can only take the most probably predictions, which might be stellar winds in this case. However i will still do some research and most probably get back to this question

It could be there because it is leftover from the Big Bang

Edit: I found an answer
The Local Intertellar Cloud is a  low density region embedded in an even lower density region, called the Local Bubble.
The Local Bubble was created by numerous stellar winds and supernovae, probably coming from a still existing OB association (group of very massive and hot stars) called the Scorpius-Centaurus association, which blew its near interstellar medium away, creating this cavity.
This isn't the only existing cavity, but there are others adjacent ones, like the Loop I Bubble.
These bubbles on the inside are almost free of interstellar medium, but on their outer surface, on their edge,they are rich of it.
Well, when the Local Bubble and the Loop I Bubble met, the  outer interstellar medium of each got into the other, leaving some traces of relatively high density, one of which is our Local Interstellar Cloud.
source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Bubble

The Local Bubble, or Local Cavity, is a relative cavity in the interstellar medium (ISM) of the Orion Arm in the Milky Way. It contains the closest of celestial neighbours and among others, the Local Interstellar Cloud (which contains the Solar System), the neighbouring G-Cloud, the Ursa Major moving group (the closest stellar moving group) and the Hyades (the nearest open cluster). It is estimated to be at least 1000 light years in size, and is defined by its neutral-hydrogen density of about 0.05 atoms/cm3, or approximately one tenth of the average for the ISM in the Milky Way (0.5 atoms/cm3), and one sixth that of the Local Interstellar Cloud (0.3 atoms/cm3).


I'd never heard of the Local Bubble (being an Astronomy lover but not an astronomer) and by extension have never heard of the Local Interstellar Cloud residing inside it and in which we reside. This is all news to me; thanks for asking, continuing to search, and ultimately finding the answer and posting it. 1) can you mention what "OB" is? 2) I'll add a block-quote of the first paragraph from your link which contains a nice chunk of gory details. It's OK to copy/paste small sections of Wikipedia as long as we indicate it is a quote and credit properly. Feel free to edit further, or roll back.

"OB" are the stellar classifications of the brightest stars, it continues "OBAFGKM".  An OB association is a loose cluster of young, bright stars, that must have formed at the same time, (as they don't last long).
